# Azure DNS zone not resolving

Tags: networking, azure, dns-hosting

I have a VM running a web API that is accessible from a public API - x.y.z.w at port 5000. I tried to attach a DNS record that aliases to this public IP in Azure -

DNS zone name - example-test123.com
Record set name - dev

In Powershell,

```
nslookup dev.example-test123.com <ns-name>.azure-dns.com.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  40.90.4.8

Name:    dev.example-test123.com
Address: x.y.z.w


Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "x.y.z.w" -Port 5000

                                                                                                                              
  ComputerName     : x.y.z.w                                                                                              
  RemoteAddress    : x.y.z.w                                                                                              
  RemotePort       : 5000                                                                                                       
  InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi                                                                                                      
  SourceAddress    : <redacted>                                                                                              
  TcpTestSucceeded : True 

Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "dev.example-test123.com" -Port 5000
WARNING: Name resolution of dev.example-test123.com failed



  
ComputerName   : dev.example-test123.com
RemoteAddress  :
InterfaceAlias :
SourceAddress  :
PingSucceeded  : False
```

Similarly, the swagger endpoint is accessible from browser through public IP, but not through domain name.

Comment: Is the domain example-test123.com or sexample-test123.com

Comment: Well spotted. Actually I didn't want to share the real domain, so I put up a made-up one for the question. But I missed the typos. I have corrected them now.

Comment: Has the domain been delegated to these Azure DNS servers?

Comment: Not sure. How can I check?

Comment: What name servers have you configured for the domain with your registrar?

Comment: Once I created the DNS zone in Azure, I was able to see that 4 name servers were already assigned. I used one of them in the nslookup command that I have put in the question, and the nslookup passes, but the Test-NetConnection command fails. One of the name servers assigned to the DNS zone I created is ns1-08.azure-dns.com.

Comment: If you want this domain to be publicly resolvable, you’ll need to register the domain at a registrar and point it to those Azure DNS servers.

Comment: How can I do that? Are domains in Azure DNS zones noy publically resolvable by default?

Comment: No.  Azure DNS is not a domain registrar, just a PaaS DNS server.

Comment: So how can I make it publically resolvable?

Comment: I’ve already answered that.

Comment: got it. Thanks! I found an alternative where I was able to set a DNS label directly in the static IP that was attached to my Azure VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an additional step to register domain with registrar as mentioned by [Greg W](https://serverfault.com/users/159910/greg-w) - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation. For my scenario, I was able to set DNS label to static IP attached to my Azure VM - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/create-fqdn